# How do I determine the authentication methods used in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, multi-factor-authentication

I am setting up an OP federation gateway between an IdentityServer4 and Azure AD B2C (IdentityServer being the gateway). As I want to benefit from the built-in MFA of the B2C, I would like to know which authentication method was used - the amr claim specified in the OpenID Connect Core specification (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken).

I have tried both the sign in v1 and v2 default policies with MFA enabled, but only receives ID tokens containing this:

```
{
  "exp": 1569784695,
  "nbf": 1569781095,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iss": "myb2cinstance.b2clogin.com/my-tenant-guid/v2.0/",
  "sub": "1b63b48a-0f5d-4e27-9cbd-44695f59ccd6",
  "aud": "6dc0a920-48dd-4297-8267-659e242b14da",
  "nonce": "defaultNonce",
  "iat": 1569781095,
  "auth_time": 1569781095,
  "tfp": "B2C_1_SignIn"
}
```

Can the amr claim be included in the token somehow? Custom policies perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

It can be included in custom policies, but you may be able to validate it using `tfp` claim which contains the ID of the policy used for authentication. One option is to have that policy ID as the contract, i.e. if that policy enforces MFA, then its presence in the token means that MFA was enforced.

Comment: can you provide any resources on how to do it with a custom policy? I was considering using policy id, but I prefer the amr claim. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide any reference documentation or an example on how to achieve this?